# OpenSSL trusted certificate error

Tags: openssl, edi

Trying to create an AS2 EDI connection with a signed MDN using the PHP AS2Secure library running on Ubuntu 14.04.

When the app issues this command:

```
openssl smime  -encrypt -in '/tmp/as2file_ipLjR3' -out '/tmp/as2file_j2HDRa' -des3 '/home/server/app/as2secure/partners/sourcingco/SourcingCoAS2.cer'
```

It produces this error:

```
unable to load certificate
140035455448736:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Any ideas where I'm getting this wrong?

Comment: As a guess, I'm thinking it's looking for a PEM file and not a CER.  http://serverfault.com/questions/254627/how-to-convert-a-cer-file-in-pem

Comment: @Andrew How can I make it look for a CER instead? That is all I am provided by this remote partner and the AS2Secure config uses the value in `sec_certificate` to encode the messages, which I'm assuming is supposed to reference the remote partner's .cer file.

Comment: if you have openSSL, why not convert the CER to PEM?  The link in my first comment gives you the command to do so.  I've only used commercial packages for AS2, not openSSL.

Comment: @Andrew converting to PEM proved to be the solution I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP AS2Secure library requires a PEM certificate file.  While some AS2 implementations rely on .cer self-signed certificate files, this particular library requires PEM.

As it relies on OpenSSL, you can convert .cer / .der via the following command:

```
 openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

This should solve the problem of the software looking for the right format.